# CentOS - Specifying an alternate redis.conf with systemctl

Tags: centos, redis

I used `systemctl` to enable automatic start up of `redis` on my server. This works fine. But I would like to change the name of my `redis.conf`, and have multiple `redis` instances.

How do I use `systemctl` to start `redis` with the non-default configuration file?

---

I used this command to start my redis instance before:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis
```